# Does the cron kill the process before starting a new one?

Tags: ubuntu, cron-task

I have a cron job running on ubuntu every 5 minutes, sometimes the task takes more than 5 minutes, so the question is does the OS kill the the old cron task, before starting new one or not?

How does the OS manage cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

No, `cron` simply starts jobs. You will end up with multiple jobs if the previous one did not finish. The opposite would be quite problematic for many use cases.